# I can't seem to configure persistence in MQTT

Tags: mqtt

I am trying MQTT on my Raspberry Pi running Raspbian.
The basic setup works, but I can't seem to configure persistence.

Following https://tutorials-raspberrypi.com/raspberry-pi-mqtt-broker-client-wireless-communication/

I installed `mosquitto mosquitto-clients`

I installed `paho-mqtt` and am running  the following script in a background process to publish temperature and humidity readings from an attached sensor.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os
import time
import sys
import Adafruit_DHT as dht
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import json
import datetime
#
# Sensor should be set to Adafruit_DHT.DHT11, Adafruit_DHT.DHT22, or Adafruit_DHT.AM2302.
sensor = dht.DHT11
pin = 4

BROKER = 'localhost'

# Data capture and upload interval in seconds.
INTERVAL=15

sensor_data = {'date': 0, 'temperature': 0, 'humidity': 0}

next_reading = time.time()

client = mqtt.Client()

# Connect to BROKER using default MQTT port and 60 seconds keepalive interval
client.connect(BROKER, 1883, 60)

client.loop_start()

try:
    while True:
        humidity,temperature = dht.read_retry(sensor, pin)
        humidity = round(humidity, 2)
        temperature = round(temperature, 2)
        print(u"Temperature: {:g}\u00b0C, Humidity: {:g}%".format(temperature, humidity))
        sensor_data['temperature'] = temperature
        sensor_data['humidity'] = humidity
        sensor_data['date'] = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0).isoformat()

#         client.publish('test_channel', json.dumps(sensor_data), 1)
        client.publish('test_channel', json.dumps(sensor_data), 2)

        next_reading += INTERVAL
        sleep_time = next_reading-time.time()
        if sleep_time > 0:
            time.sleep(sleep_time)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

client.loop_stop()
client.disconnect()
```

This works and I can see the messages on another Pi with `mosquitto_sub -h IPaddress -v -t test_channel` but this only works while the process is running. I want the Broker to save messages until the subscriber connects.

I added "persistence true" to a file `/etc/mosquitto/conf.d/Milliways.conf` and the log file shows messages like

```
1547597521: Saving in-memory database to /var/lib/mosquitto/mosquitto.db.
```

The database does not seem to contain any relevant data.

I have read the Documentation on https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/#publishing and the `man` for mosquitto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Persistence is set when you send the message to the broker, by default messages are not persistent.

Add a fourth parameter to `client.publish()`, namely `true`, which sets the `retain` quality on the message, which translates to persistence.

Comment: This seems to work, even if it does not do what I expected as "if set to True, the message will be set as the “last known good”/retained message for the topic." I had hoped for an option to retain a number of unread messages as "Set the maximum number of messages with QoS>0 that can be part way through their network flow at once. Defaults to 20." implies.